# Writing to a new file if it doesn't exist, and appending to a file if it does

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, append

I have a program which writes a user's `highscore` to a text file. The file is named by the user when they choose a `playername`.

If the file with that specific username already exists, then the program should append to the file (so that you can see more than one `highscore`). And if a file with that username doesn't exist (for example, if the user is new), it should create a new file and write to it.

Here's the relevant, so far not working, code:

```
try: 
    with open(player): #player is the varible storing the username input
        with open(player, 'a') as highscore:
            highscore.write("Username:", player)

except IOError:
    with open(player + ".txt", 'w') as highscore:
        highscore.write("Username:", player)
```

The above code creates a new file if it doesn't exist, and writes to it. If it exists, nothing has been appended when I check the file, and I get no errors.

Comment: What is the purpose of the first `with open(player):` statement? Also, in your exception handler, you are creating a different file, `player + '.txt'`, than you were trying to write to in the first place.

Comment: @MarkkuK I took that from another question at stackoverflow where you check if a file exist. So the with open(player): checks if the file exist, at least so I thought. Okey I see, just thought I had to use the ".txt" for the file to be a text-file.

Comment: in any case, you can just use `open(whatever,'a') as highscore:`, and it will do what you want: create the file if it does not exist, or append to it if it does exist

Comment: @MarkkuK Gosh you're right, gotta love python for it simplicity. Thank you!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It's not clear to me exactly where the high-score that you're interested in is stored, but the code below should be what you need to check if the file exists and append to it if desired. I prefer this method to the "try/except".

```
import os
player = 'bob'

filename = player+'.txt'

if os.path.exists(filename):
    append_write = 'a' # append if already exists
else:
    append_write = 'w' # make a new file if not

highscore = open(filename,append_write)
highscore.write("Username: " + player + '\n')
highscore.close()
```

Comment: Isn't this prone to a race condition?

Comment: why not just open it with mode "a+"?

Comment: what if we just use `open(filename, 'a')`, it also creates the file if does not exist and append if exists.

Comment: @EricdesCourtis "a" and "a+" will not let you seek to arbitrary offsets (only to the end of the file).

Comment: _I prefer this method to the "try/except"._ Is personal preference more important than the  fact that the [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html?highlight=eafp#term-eafp) style is generally considered better in Python?

Comment: It seems that using `open(file, 'a')` is enough to append to a file (if the file does not exit, it will be created). Tested on Python 3.6 in CentOS.

Comment: @jdhao that may be true in Python 3, but when the question was asked, Python 2 was very common

Comment: append_write = ( 'a' if os.path.exists(filename) else 'w')

Answer (score 169):

Have you tried mode 'a+'?

```
with open(filename, 'a+') as f:
    f.write(...)
```

Note however that `f.tell()` will return 0 in Python 2.x. See https://bugs.python.org/issue22651 for details.

Comment: Upvote, though you need to prefix this suggestion with "if you're not concerned with the value reported by `f.tell()`".

Comment: I'm concerned about portability of `a+` because of this in the docs: `on some Unix systems means that all writes append to the end of the file regardless of the current seek position`.

Comment: @JarrodSmith Not a real concern IMO. From docs: `'a' for appending (which on some Unix systems means that all writes append to the end of the file regardless of the current seek position).` I think this is fine for most uses of files (always appending for example). If you need to seek at specific offsets then you probably won't open files this way anyway.

Comment: I've tried both `a` and `a+` on mac os high sierra on python 2.7.15 and both append to the end of the file, and `f.tell()` reports the same in both (not 0). The bug linked also has some portable workarounds, e.g. manually set the seek position to the end of the file, or use the `io` module instead which doesn't have that bug.

Comment: Why `a+` when you can just `a`?

Comment: This is most correct. If the file does not exist, 'a+' will create it whereas 'a' will fail with a file not found exception (using Python 3.7 on Raspian).

Answer (score 56):

Just open it in [`'a'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/python-open-built-in-function-difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r) mode:

> `a`   Open for writing. The file is created if it does not exist. The stream is positioned at the end of the file.

```
with open(filename, 'a') as f:
    f.write(...)
```

To see whether you're writing to a new file, check the stream position. If it's zero, either the file was empty or it is a new file.

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as f:
    if f.tell() == 0:
        print('a new file or the file was empty')
        f.write('The header\n')
    else:
        print('file existed, appending')
    f.write('Some data\n')
```

If you're still using Python 2, to work around [the bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue22651), either add `f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)` right after `open` or use [`io.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that if the file's parent folder doesn't exist you'll get the same error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Below is another solution which handles this case: 
(*) I used `sys.stdout` and `print` instead of `f.write` just to show another use case

```
# Make sure the file's folder exist - Create folder if doesn't exist
folder_path = 'path/to/'+folder_name+'/'
if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
     os.makedirs(folder_path)

print_to_log_file(folder_path, "Some File" ,"Some Content")
```

Where the internal `print_to_log_file` just take care of the file level:

```
# If you're not familiar with sys.stdout - just ignore it below (just a use case example)
def print_to_log_file(folder_path ,file_name ,content_to_write):

   #1) Save a reference to the original standard output       
    original_stdout = sys.stdout   
    
    #2) Choose the mode
    write_append_mode = 'a' #Append mode
    file_path = folder_path + file_name
    if (if not os.path.exists(file_path) ):
       write_append_mode = 'w' # Write mode
     
    #3) Perform action on file
    with open(file_path, write_append_mode) as f:
        sys.stdout = f  # Change the standard output to the file we created.
        print(file_path, content_to_write)
        sys.stdout = original_stdout  # Reset the standard output to its original value
```

---

Consider the following states:

```
'w'  --> Write to existing file
'w+' --> Write to file, Create it if doesn't exist
'a'  --> Append to file
'a+' --> Append to file, Create it if doesn't exist
```

In your case I would use a different approach and just use `'a'` and `'a+'`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using the `pathlib` module (python's [object-oriented filesystem paths](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html))

Just for kicks, this is perhaps the latest pythonic version of the solution.

```py
from pathlib import Path 

path = Path(f'{player}.txt')
path.touch()  # default exists_ok=True
with path.open('a') as highscore:
   highscore.write(f'Username:{player}')
```

Comment: This answer's clean and relatively new compared to the rest. @ohailolcat - what makes it more pythonic, exactly? Not that this isn't pythonic, but it also does require importing a new module. Why not just 'a+'?