# every time I give an output, the answer should settle in a table with record of the previous outputs . How do I do that?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import math
def newtons_method(a):
 #a = int(input("Enter the value of a :"))
 x = int(input("Enter the value of x :"))

 while True:
               print (x)
               y = (x + a/x) / 2
               if y == x:
                   return float(y)
                   break
               x = y
def mathlibs(a):
     result = math.sqrt(a)
     return float(result)

def test_square_root(a):
    A = newtons_method(a)
    B = mathlibs(a)
    print(B)
    Difference = B-A
    answers = list()
    answer = ''


    print('{:<10s}{:>50s}{:>30s}{:>20s}'.format('a','square root newton method','sqrtlibrary','Difference'))
    answer = print('{:<10f}{:>50f}{:>30f}{:>20f}'.format(a,A,B,Difference))
    answers.append(answer)
    print(answers)

test_square_root(565)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Please at least include some text in your question, provide a [mre], and [format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) your code correctly (especially for Python code, because indenting is part of the language!). Regarding your code, what do you think that `print` returns?

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.

I am guessing that you need to store your answers even after your program terminates. You could create a file and append your answers for the following executions of your square program. Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432912/writing-to-a-new-file-if-it-doesnt-exist-and-appending-to-a-file-if-it-does).

Alternatively, if you want to get fancier about your program import sqlite3 to create a database table for your answers.

Comment: Hi , your're right, i need to store my answers and print them so that it appears as a long list