# Overwriting an existing txt file with new data using Python OS module

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, txt

I am following the code mentioned by SO User "qmorgan" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432912/writing-to-a-new-file-if-it-doesnt-exist-and-appending-to-a-file-if-it-does), basically I am trying to create new text file if file doesn't exist. If file exist then overwrite the existing file.
For this my code looks like below. The issue I am facing is using 'a' for writing the file it is append the text instead of overwriting it. As 'a' function is to append the text under first if condition. If I use "W" instead of "a" then it would only write last record, instead of all the records.

Thanks in advance for help and efforts!

**Python code**

```
filename='test.txt'
  
tables=["schema.table1","schema2.table2"]
    
for table in tables:
   cur.execute (f'select count(*) from {table};')
   result=cur.fecthone()
   count=result[0] if result else 0
   for row in result:
       if os.path.exists(filename):
            append_write='a'
            my_file.close()
       else:
          append_write='w+'
       my_file=open(filename,append_write)
       my_file.write(f"the table {table} contained {count} rows. \n")
       my_file.close()
```

Comment: What is `o`? Is that supposed to be `0`? There's no need for that `if`, since `SELECT COUNT(*)` will *always* return a row.

Comment: Open the file *once* at the top. Then write to it in a loop.

Comment: @Barmar..correct..sorry will the edit the code

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga..where exactly ?

Comment: Before the `for table in tables:` command. If you do it this way, you don't need to use `os.path.exists()`. Just use `w` mode and it will always overwrite the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open the file once at the beginning, not separately for each query. Then you can simply use `w` mode to overwrite it.

There's also no need for the `for row in result:` loop, since you never use `row` anywhere. `result` is a tuple with just a single element, the count returned by `COUNT(*)`, there's nothing else to loop over.

```
filename='test.txt'
  
tables=["schema.table1","schema2.table2"]
    
with open(filename, 'w') as my_file:
    for table in tables:
        cur.execute(f'select count(*) from {table};')
        (count,) = cur.fetchone()
        my_file.write(f"the table {table} contained {count} rows. \n")
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! Was wondering if I need to close my_file.close() ?

Comment: Why? Don't you know that `with` does that automatically? It's the whole point of using `with`.